# The value of a private member "current" is changed abnormally in the end of a member function

Tags: c++, private-members

I met a very weird behavior on a private variable in class.

Problem Description: The value of a private member "current" in class lapi_xmeef_table is changed abnormally in the end of a member function.

class 1: lapi_xmeef
class 2: lapi_xmeef_table (is friend of lapi_xmeef, so can access private variables in lapi_xmeef directly or via public interfaces)

```
class lapi_xmeef {
  friend class lapi_xmeef_table;
  ...
  short bias_frag_layer;
  int bias_frag_index;
  ...
  public:
    // Add constructor
    lapi_xmeef();
    // Add public interface
    ...
    void bias_frag(int *li, int *fi);

};

class lapi_xmeef_table {
  private:
    lapi_xmeef *current;
    ...
  public:
    lapi_xmeef_table(Lapi_ctl *ctl, int num_layer);
    ...
    void get_bias(int *li, int *fi);
    ...
};
```

A private variable in lapi_xmeef_table called "current" is a current iterator (a class lapi_xmeef).

The member function does nothing but read only, it copies two values from its private members. Show as below

```
void lapi_xmeef::bias_frag(int *li, int *fi)
{
   *li = (short)bias_frag_layer;
   *fi = bias_frag_index;
}
```

Problem function and variable:

```
void lapi_xmeef_table::get_bias(int *li, int *fi)
{
// current is (lapi_xmeef *) 0x2a9a93c7f0 (a valid address)
  current->bias_frag(li, fi);
// current is (lapi_xmeef *) 0x2a000000df (a invalid address)
}
```

Before calling the function current is (lapi_xmeef *) 0x2a9a93c7f0 (a valid address)
After, current is (lapi_xmeef *) 0x2a000000df (a invalid address)

This doesn't happen every time when the member function is called, before this weird behavior, it's called many time without problem.

When next time, a member in current is being accessed, a seg fault occurs because a invalid address is dereferenced.

Now my solution is have a temp pointer to save the value of current before calling its member function, then restore it after calling. It works.

```
void lapi_xmeef_table::get_bias(int *li, int *fi)
{
  lapi_xmeef *temp = current;
  current->bias_frag(li, fi);
  current = temp;
}
```

But I really want to know why and how to fix it instead of this tricky way.

Why the value of private variable is changed which is expected to be the same?

Any problem in the way accessing a private varibale? Is prefix needed or the point "this" needed? I tried this->current->bias_frag(li, fi); which doesn't help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are probably using a dangling pointer, and overwriting the memory.  In order to diagnose what your problem is, you need to write a minimal example that completely compiles and demonstrates the problem.  You need to do this because you do not understand what is happening, and the "unimportant" details you leave out could easily be the reason why it is happening.  And by complete example, I mean it should have an `int main()`, all classes should be fully defined, and you should be able to compile and run it as written.

Answer (score 1):

What's likely happening is that you have unintended *pointer aliasing* going on.  One of the `li` or `fi` pointers is pointing to the same location as `&current`, so when you dereference and assign to them inside `bias_frag`, you're accidentally overwriting `current` or part of it.

To fix it, you need to figure out why you're getting aliased pointers by tracing the data flow backwards.  For starters, crank up your compiler's warning level and fix all warnings.

Do not try to work around it by saving the value of `current` and restoring it -- that's just a bandage over a much bigger problem and is not a long-term solution.  You've already entered the land of undefined behavior, and trying to dig yourself out is not going to work.

Comment: The function calling get_bias could be going out of scope and so if he is using a temporary variable, it too will go out of scope.